# HTML5Up Overflow how to put links on the picture

Tags: javascript, html, css, templates, jquery-html5uploader

I downloaded this html5 template for a project https://html5up.net/overflow and I dont know how to put a link for github on the pictures displayed in the gallery (those 8 ) I want that when I click the pic and expand , the next click should sent me to a link and not to scroll over the next or previous picture.I tried to check the code but i found it to complicated for my actual level to figure it out . I am hoping that i can get some help here :) thank you

EDIT: I actualy need help in this part of code

```
            <div class="inner gallery">
                <div class="row gtr-0">
                    <div class="col-3 col-12-mobile"><a href="images/fulls/Pairs.png" class="image fit"><img src="images/thumbs/Pairs.png" alt="" title="A little game in"/></a></div>
                    <div class="col-3 col-12-mobile"><a href="images/fulls/Chrome.png" class="image fit"><img src="images/thumbs/Chrome.png" alt="" title="Dressed in Clarity" /></a></div>
                    <div class="col-3 col-12-mobile"><a href="images/fulls/MP3.png" class="image fit"><img src="images/thumbs/MP3.png" alt="" title="Raven" /></a></div>
                    <div class="col-3 col-12-mobile"><a href="images/fulls/Studenti.png" class="image fit"><img src="images/thumbs/Studenti.png" alt="" title="I'll have a cup of Disneyland, please" /></a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

When I click them twice I would like to send me to other links on other sites

Comment: Please provide what you have done so far

Comment: Please go read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Code relevant to your problem belongs directly into your question, in text form and properly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

if im understanding correctly what do you want do this

Change in your code..

```
<a href="#banner" class="button style2 scrolly-middle">Proceed as anticipated</a>
```

for

```
<a href="https://www...(URL)">Proceed as anticipated</a>
```

dont forget to remove remove class="..."

Comment: Actually I dont need help in that part of code, I just edited my post to be more clearly

Comment: so... do you wanna see the images in github? 1 click go to github and see the image no?